# What's the meaning of MOV EAX, DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+8h] and how can I translate it into AT&T format?

Tags: c++, assembly, codeblocks, inline-assembly

I'm using Code::Blocks to code, but one of the code I referenced is from Visual C++,so I have difficulties on the difference...:(

the full code are here

```
NAKED void ijlWrite()
{
__asm {
    PUSH    EBP
    MOV     EBP, ESP
    MOV     EAX, DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+8h]
    MOV     ECX, ssQuality
    MOV     DWORD PTR DS:[EAX+50h], ECX
    MOV     EDX, DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+0Ch]
    PUSH    EDX
    MOV     EAX, DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+08h]
    PUSH    EAX
    CALL    lpfnIJLWrite //a global variable
    POP     EBP
    RETN
}
}
```

I'll be very grateful if you translate them all.

P.S. I also don't know how to translate RETN. how to do it? The cheatsheet doesn't have such things:(

Comment: You have a synthetic cheat sheet [there](http://www.imada.sdu.dk/Courses/DM516/Litteratur/IntelnATT.htm)

Comment: Also see [there](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html), since GCC inline asm requires you to declare a lot of things MSVC's inline asm doesn't.

Comment: And you are sure that the calling conventions make a straight translation possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
MOV     EAX, DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+8h]
```

is equivalent to

```
movl %ss:8(%ebp), %eax
```

You just swap the order of the source and destination, the `DWORD` translates to an `l` suffix. The `%ss:` prefix is strictly unnecessary, it's the default when using `EBP` based memory access.

Comment: `retn` is just `ret`.  `retf` translates into `lret`.

Answer (score 4):

Can't you just write the function in C++? A little more type information would help, but how about this?

```
void ijlWrite(int* p, int i)
{
    p[80] = ssQuality;
    lpfnIJLWrite(p, i);
}
```

Comment: actually the `ijlWrite` is from a dll and the code tried to hook the dll and change a parameter and then run the original function.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's

```
movl %ss:8(%ebp), %eax
```

See [this](http://www.imada.sdu.dk/Courses/DM516/Litteratur/IntelnATT.htm) for a quick reference.

Comment: You're the second to link that "reference" but it's a http:403 for me.

Comment: @Pixelchemist, use Wayback Machine: http://web.archive.org/web/20120822123638/http://www.imada.sdu.dk/Courses/DM516/Litteratur/IntelnATT.htm